# writing application that will catch user and pass of yahoo mail if right go to yahoomail

Tags: php, ssl, authentication, https

for this app using SSL and connecting to HTTPS is needed I know general things about HTTPS and SSL but I don't know from where I must start to code in PHP any steps to follow?
It's just a project I'm a student and a beginner It will not be implemented in any website I just want to see how to code my aim is just learning I don't have any goal to implement this 
implementing is redeculus cause I know no one has eager to go to it!
cause privacy is missing

it's just learning using connect to https I just want some information about code

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I haven't website it's just a project for showing https connecting and connect to ymail

Comment: I'm trying to make https connection downloading certificate  and using these things

Comment: is it against the law!? I don't think so!

Comment: You may have to convince people your project isn't nefarious before anyone will help you...

Comment: Your edit just made your question worse. The why babbling is not very relevant. But it's still totally unclear what it is you are actually trying to do. Tip: Write a new summary, and put the steps you want to take into key points (line per line, not in a text block).

Comment: thanks Mario I will in the next Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `curl` to post user-id and password to yahoo's login form and then use various curl options to handle redirects and store and send cookies to the login module. if successful you will get the inbox page. include headers like user agent,content-type,encoding,etc to fool yahoo to think that you are a browser. use `firefox` addon `liveHTTPheaders` to once login to yahoo mail and have a look at the headers `firefox` sends to yahoo and try to mimic that in your script. once you are able to log in, get the html from yahoo and use `xpath` on that to get specific parts of the page. have a look at

Comment: can't I download any certificate and convince yahoo allowing me to access?

Comment: @Negin: havent tried this but i can speculate that sites wouldnt allow scripts to access their page. To access a site's services programatically, the best way is to use their API. yahoo does provide an API. have a look at [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/everything.html)